# Odd problem with bash script running by cron

Tags: bash, cron

I have bash script running by cron for every hour in my Docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/generate_signing_key -k $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -r $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION > /usr/local/nginx/s3_signature_key.txt

{ read -r val1
  read -r val2
  sed -i 's! aws_signing_key .*; *$! aws_signing_key '$val1';!; s! aws_key_scope .*; *$! aws_key_scope '$val2';!;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
} < /usr/local/nginx/s3_signature_key.txt

if [ -z "$(pgrep nginx)" ]
  then
     nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  else
     nginx -s reload
fi
```

So it is running Python script `generate_signing_key` and save result to `s3_signature_key.txt` file. Then `sed` takes some values and update `nginx` config.

Script is working when run manually and if I run it in the cron way:
`cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly`

Unfortunately if cron run it itself then it is zeroing the output `s3_signature_key.txt` file and erase values in nginx config.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Where do you define `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` ?

Comment: This is not a problem with `bash`, but the environment in which `cron` runs jobs.  I have voted to move to ServerFault, where it would be a dupe of this: https://serverfault.com/questions/337631/crontab-execution-doesnt-have-the-same-environment-variables-as-executing-user

Comment: `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` are defined with docker run -e option and are present in Docker container environment.

Comment: John: If I replace `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` `$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` with static values it is doing the same.

Comment: @SynRomana There's no such thing as the "docker container environment" -- each process has its own private environment, and for `cron` jobs that environment is nearly empty. I'm not familiar with `generate_signing_key`, but I'll bet it's dependent on something that isn't set up in `cron` jobs. Suggestions: redirect its error output somewhere so you can see any messages it prints, and add error checking to your script (e.g. if `generate_signing_key` exits with an error status, the script *should not continue*).